# Python Class Confusion: How to print object attributes returned by a function

Tags: python

I am new to python 2.7 and just getting into classes. I wrote the block of code below for section 13.2 from "How Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning With Python"

When I call the `print_time` function to print the returned attributes from the `add_time` function I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "13.py", line 49, in <module>
print_time(done_time)
File "13.py", line 10, in print_time
print time.hour,':',time.minute
AttributeError: Time instance has no attribute 'hour'
```

Why is this? Do I need to explicitly tell python which attributes in the `done_time` class to print?

```
class Time:
    pass

def print_time(time):
    print time.hour,':',time.minute

def time_add(t1, t2):
    time_sum = Time()
    time_sum.hours = t1.hour + t2.hour
    time_sum.minutes = t1.minute + t2.minute
    return time_sum

current_time = Time()
current_time.hour = 9
current_time.minute = 00

duration = Time()
duration.hour = 2
duration.minute = 30

done_time = time_add(current_time, duration)
print_time(done_time)
```

Comment: Your indentations are way off. Make sure to put the class functions within the class. Edit: my mistake... Didn't fully read the question ;)

Comment: @not_a_robot No, the code is properly indented and this code reproduces the exact error OP states. The error has to do with calling the wrong attribute names.

Comment: @not_a_robot What do you mean? His indention is fine. How do you know he wanted those functions in his class? Looks more like he was creating a skeleton class to me.

Comment: You have a typo in your `time_add` function. `time_sum.hours` should be `time_sum.hour`. And `time_sum.minutes` should be `time_sum.minute`

Answer (score 1):

The overall structure of the code is a bit weird. I'm assuming that maybe this is deliberate per the book you are following to help teach towards a proper design for this code down the road? Either way, the problem is actually because you are mixing your `hour` and `hours` attributes (`minute` and `minutes` for that matter as well). I'm not sure if this is code you created on your own, but, starting here:

```
done_time = time_add(current_time, duration)
```

What is happening is that your `time_add` *function* is returning a `Time` object with attributes, `hours` and `minutes`.

The following line, you do:

```
print_time(done_time)
```

Which, takes you to your `print_time` *function*, which then tries to reference the `hour` and `minute` attribute, which you clearly do not have in `done_time`. Based on your previous function, you, as stated, assigned `hours` and `minutes`. To immediately fix your problem, your `print_time` should be referencing `hours` and `minutes`:

```
def print_time(time):
    print time.hours,':',time.minutes
```

Comment: This clarified and fixed the problem. New to programming, thank you!